# What is the perfect age for a child to start piano lessons?

Tags: guitar, piano, voice, lessons, children

My son of 3.5 year old, and my daughter of 1.5 year old, are both showing good ear, musical capabilities and intetests. I am a 19 years experienced guitarist and I am about to start music lessons for them. What can be the best age for them to start the lessons?

Both of them show interest in piano, singing and maybe guitar.

Comment: It might be the wrong question. There's no minimum age for interacting with music and learning and growing from it. There might be some skills needed for traditional private lessons that determine readiness—the ability to take direction, focus on a task for at least 15 minutes, meet adult social expectations about "behaving," etc. But there are other "musical play" type curricula that can be better suited for pre-kindergarten ages, like Kindermusik.

Comment: @AndyBonner - minimum is different from optimum, which OP seems to be enquiring about, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, they are having kind of a Kindermusik in their schools, and yes, I'm looking for an optimum age. I Agree that there's no minimum age (I have been able to show them they have favorite notes in fact), but of course they still have no attention longer than 15 minutes, so that's where I'm stuck, if I send them to music lessons, they may not show interest and that opportunity could be lost, instead of waiting for a precise age when they are capable of showing interest and "behaving" so they start making it a productive session instead of thinking it's only for playing a little while.

Comment: Playing or 'playing' - it should all be the same for kids. It's often through 'play' that they ( and, let's face it the rest of us) learn best!

Comment: WHen the child wants to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no best age as in how many years they've been alive!

The best *time* is when they show enough interest and can concentrate and practise well enough to cope with lessons. For some that may be 3, others may never attain an 'age' when that's a viable possibility.

So, from that point of view, there will be no concrete answer.

As a musician yourself, why not encourage some musicality by providing some instruments appropriate to their capability - size and playability. When you see improvement, and feel (and they feel) that they're ready to be left with a stranger for 20 mins, half an hour, and you can pay for that privilege, that's the age.

EDIT: For *piano* lessons, specifically, (from your header), size would be a salient factor. Ability to stretch several piano keys is a consideration, ability to reach pedals, not so. Perhaps a mini piano or small key synth would be appropriate.

Comment: OK pretty clear and makes me have a plan. Now it takes me to ask another question, I'll do it separately. It's about asking which instrument or brand, but I know that maybe here's not the right forum for comparing products and brands, I'll check it separately. Thanks!